# Data from Firestore into the data object of a Vue.js app

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get this working on Firebase hosting. It is retreiving the data and logs it to the console however vue does not appear to be displaying the username:

```
  <script>
    var config = {
        apiKey: "Long Key",
        authDomain: "myUrl.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://myUrl.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "myUrl",
        storageBucket: "myUrl.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "12345"
    };
    var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
    db = firebase.firestore(app);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <p>Username: {{user.username}}</p>
  </div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script>
var user = db.collection("users").doc("chordscribble").get().then(function(doc){
  console.log(doc.data()); 
});
console.log(user); //logs {username:"admin"}
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    "user":user
  }  
});
</script>
```

What is the right way to get the data from firestore into the data object of vue? Also, is there anyway to just query and return the string "admin" as opposed to the whole object? For instance, I tried:

```
   db.collection("users").doc("chordscribble").get().then(function(doc){
      console.log(doc.data("username")); 
    });
    console.log(user); // hoping for "admin"
...and tried:

   db.collection("users").doc("chordscribble").get().then(function(doc){
      console.log(doc.data().username); 
    });
    console.log(user);  //hoping for "admin"
```